# Using unittests and moto to mock AWS

Tags: python, python-unittest, moto

I am used to `pytest` approach for unit testing, without using classes.  Today I wanted to give a try to `unittest` and I wanted to encapsulate my tests inside a [TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).

Then consider this sample test class:

```py
import unittest
import moto
import boto3

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    @moto.mock_ssm
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
        cls.ssm_client.put_parameter(Name='test', Value='foo', Type='String')

    @moto.mock_ssm
    def test_something(self):
        value = self.ssm_client.get_parameter(Name='test').get('Parameter').get('Value')
        self.assertEqual(value, 'foo')
```

Why is not the parameter placed in `setUpClass` visible from the test?  I could imagine that by using the `@moto.mock_ssm` decorator there it would all have been done in the mocked context.

I can, however, place the parameter within `test_something` as just:

```py
@moto.mock_ssm
def test_something(self):
    self.ssm_client.put_parameter(Name='test', Value='foo', Type='String')
    value = self.ssm_client.get_parameter(Name='test').get('Parameter').get('Value')
    self.assertEqual(value, 'foo')
```

And then it (obviously) works.  Why not with my first approach?  I do not want to be populating the fake *ssm* parameter for each test that will rely on it.  What is the best way of doing so here?

The reason why I am asking this is because the class I want to test requires this parameter when it is initialised.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. If you put it in setupClass, then you don't have to do it for every single test function

Comment: But my issue is, that it does not work when placed in `setUpClass`.  Maybe I was not clear enough, but the mocked parameter stored in `SSM` is unreachable from any other test, unless I explicitly place (again) the parameter there.

My assumption was that by placing it in `setUpClass` it would be visible from any test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mock-decorators are scoped for that particular function, so data created inside that function will only be available there.

Instead, you can use the class-decorator:

```
import unittest
import moto
import boto3


@moto.mock_ssm
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    client = None

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.client = boto3.client('ssm')
        self.client.put_parameter(Name='test', Value='foo', Type='String')

    def test_something(self):
        value = self.client.get_parameter(Name='test').get('Parameter').get('Value')
        self.assertEqual(value, 'foo')
```

Note that I've switched to `setUp`, instead of `setUpClass`. Because setUpClass is a classmethod, it is executed before the decorator is applied, and it will try to execute this method against AWS itself.